I failed to use cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy
I'm unfamiliar with C++ and CUDA but trying to learn them both. I tried to use cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy but failed.
Source code is:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define cugo(ans) execute_cuda_runtime((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__)

namespace calcu {
    namespace cpu {
        int var; 
    }

    namespace gpu {
        __device__ int* var;
    }

    void execute_cuda_runtime(cudaError_t code, const char* fname, int line) {
        if (code != cudaSuccess) {
            printf("CUDA execution error at %s:%d\n", fname, line);
            printf("Error is %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(code));
            std::exit(886);
        }
    }

    void cuda_test_print(int useless);
}

namespace calcu {
    __global__ void cuda_test_print_kernel(int useless) {
        if (gpu::var == nullptr) {
            printf("wtf... gpu::var is nullptr\n");
        } else {
            printf("ftw... gpu::var is %p\n", gpu::var);
        }
    }

    void cuda_test_print(int useless) {
        cuda_test_print_kernel<<<1, 1>>>(useless);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace calcu;

    cpu::var = 1;

    cugo(cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu::var, sizeof(int)));

    cugo(cudaMemcpy(gpu::var, &cpu::var, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cuda_test_print(0);

    cudaFree(gpu::var);

    return 0;
}


When I ran these codes, wtf... gpu::var is nullptr is printed which means that gpu::var is a nullptr, and cudaMemcpy seems not to work. cugo never report that cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy failed. Could anyone help me out?

The first argument to cudaMalloc should be the address of a variable on the host, not on the device. If you want to use that pointer on the device, you need to copy its value over there with cudaMemcpy first. (Learning Cuda without at least an "intermediate" understanding of C++ is painful. In particular, you need to be very comfortable around memory and pointers.)

These two lines are broken:
cugo(cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu::var, sizeof(int)));
cugo(cudaMemcpy(gpu::var, &cpu::var, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

gpu::var is a device symbol. That has special meaning in CUDA — in the standard compilation model it is statically defined at translation unit scope in the GPU memory space and must be accessed using the symbol APIs.
To do what you want, the code would need to look something like this:
int *dev_ptr
cugo(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, sizeof(int)));
cugo(cudaMemcpy(dev_ptr, &cpu::var, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

cugo(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(gpu::var, &dev_ptr, sizeof(int*))); 

[code written in browser, on a phone, on a boat, in the middle of the Baltic, never compiled, use at own risk]
The critical part is the last API call. You must allocate and copy to a GPU address and copy that GPU address to gpu::var with a symbol API.

Thanks for your suggestion, gpu::var is a device symbol because I declare it as __device__ int* var?

Yes, that is what __device__ signifies

Thanks. It works well with the minimum code. But I met invalid device symbol error when calling cudaMemcpyToSymbol after I transplanted such modification to real codes. This error has confused me for many days. I don't know the reason. Sometimes I just tried to add * or & with knowing nothing and it may work.

I thought this time the reason may be that I have no knowledge about how to use extern

I can’t comment on code which I can’t see.  You provided code in your question and I told you what was wrong with it. As I said in my answer, __device__ symbols have translation unit scope by default. If you don’t know what that implies, now is the time to do some studying until you understand it. And if you are trying to cross translation unit boundaries, then you need to use separate compilation and device linking to build the code. Again, these things are well documented if you search for them
